# Python PIL image reproduction

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am new to PIL and Python and I have a question related to the API.

I have an Image

```
img = Image.new('RGB', (1, 2))
```

And I have a list of tuples

```
x = [(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)]
```

I do `img.putdata(x)`

and `img.save('C:\\somename.jpeg')`

Later on when I reload the Image and do

```
img2 = Image.open('C:\\somename.jpeg')

y = [p for p in img2.getdata()]
```

The data 'y' that I actually get back is

```
[(255, 255, 255), (251, 251, 251)]
```

I am not able to understand why this is happening? 
Please let me know if anyone has some pointers related to this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jpeg is a lossy compression format and doesn't guarantee pixel by pixel reproduction.  Try saving the image in a lossless format.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly, thanks! I used the png format, gif should also work I believe.